# Is there a way to use Google Chrome extensions in Firefox browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I switched to Firefox few days ago and i didn't find some extensions that i was using in chrome in Firefox Add-ons Store. I'm wondering if there is a method to use Chrome extensions in Firefox ?

Answer (score 2):

No,  it is no longer possible. Chrome store foxified was discontinued.

You can see the comment from the maintainer here
https://github.com/Noitidart/Chrome-Store-Foxified/issues/122

> Excuse my ignoring of all the issues. Mozilla keeps changing things.
>   The latest is some issues with addons.mozilla.org fetch requests.
>
> The effort I put into extension development isn't working out. I have
>   to do side jobs so I can fund the time I spend developing. I wish I
>   could make extension development my primary contribution, however it
>   can never get to this point, extensions just don't work like that. I
>   tried, I put up a contribute sign and I want to thank everyone that
>   contributed, I have got $318 USD in the past year. I made an effort to
>   thank everyone that contributed, and will be going through again to
>   make sure I didn't miss sending thank you notes.
>
> I have moved into mobile apps which pays for itself.
>
> If anyone knows of anyone that can invest in any kind of development
>   (browser, mobile, desktop), I would love to chat.
>
> I have not yet removed the extension because it is still working in
>   older versions of the browser, including ESR release channel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out this webExtension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chrome-store-foxified/

Remember to read the description first.